# Oracle Developer Tools (ODT) & Visual Studio 2017 Integration

Tags: oracle, edmx, visual-studio-2017, odt.net

I need to create *ADO.NET model* from *Oracle 12 DB*. We are using **VS2017**. I've installed **ODAC** and **ODT for VS** *(**2015**, since there is no version for **2017**)* according to recommendations in internet. However, *EDMX model* creation dialog does not show up **Oracle DB** in data source list (it's present in **Connect to Database** dialog section though). My suspicion is **ODT for VS2015** is not compatible with **VS2017**. Is it true?
What i also tried to do was to add **ODT.Net.Managed** key to *Registry* with proper path to corresponding DLL, but this did not help either.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017 (12.2.0.1.0) is now available for download.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html

BUT, big BUT:

It does NOT work in VS2017 Community Edition. It does work for the PRO and Enterprise editions.
See here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4009365?start=37&tstart=0

Comment: it's compatible with ODT for VS2015?

Comment: Be aware that you have to deinstall an install ODT VS 2017 MSI Package every time you update VS 2017, because edmx will break.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ORACLE ODT for VS2017 is not available, ORACLE has promised the VS2017 for years, but the latest information is that they are in trouble, and the VS2017 will be resolved as soon as it is solved.